# Two Foreign Keys generated with EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I get 2 foreign keys begin generated. How can I solve this? My code is as follows:

Note: the association with `Person` and `User` is 1-to-1-or-0. A `User` may or may not have a `Person`.

```
public class User : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
}

public class Person: Entity
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PersonSchool> PersonSchool{ get; set; }
}
```

Entity configuration:

```
public class UserEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{ 
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("User");
        builder.HasKey(c => c.Id);
        builder.Property(c => c.Name).IsRequired(true);
    }
}

public class PersonEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Person> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Person");
        builder.HasKey(c => c.Id);
        builder.Property(c => c.FirstName).IsRequired(true);
        builder.Property(c => c.LastName).IsRequired(true);
        builder.HasOne(i => i.User)
           .WithOne()
           .HasForeignKey<Person>(rl => rl.UserId)
           .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    }
}
```

Result:

I am copying part of the snippet from the migration code. As you can see, there are 2 foreign keys created, `UserId` and `UserId1`

```
constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Person", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Person_User_UserId",
                    column: x => x.UserId,
                    principalTable: "User",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Person_User_UserId1",
                    column: x => x.UserId1,
                    principalTable: "User",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I overlooked the additional navigation property User.Person that isn't properly configured.  This

```
builder.HasOne(i => i.User)
   .WithOne()
   .HasForeignKey<Person>(rl => rl.UserId)
   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

should be

```
builder.HasOne(i => i.User)
   .WithOne(u => u.Person)
   .HasForeignKey<Person>(rl => rl.UserId)
   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

If you don't tell EF that User.Person is the inverse navigation property of Person.User it will configure two relationships.